# Duplicate key with more values MYSQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Basically I have a table like this.
I need to use duplicate key for update.

```
    Author_ID       Book_ID     Rating
    ==================================
    1               1           5.5
    1               2           8.5
    1               3           9
    2               1           6.5
    2               2           7
```

So, in the above table, if I need to update the rating alone for Author_ID - 1 and Book_ID - 1 from 5.5 to 8
How can I achieve this?

In short, update only the rating for each author with book using Duplicate key.

## EDIT

Sorry Gentleman,
My question is - Check for row exists - if exists then update - else insert.
A single query to do the insert or to update. 
Something similar to that of ON DUPLICATE for two row values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

You have composite primary key on `Author_ID` and `Book_ID`, do you?

If you don't, first `ALTER TABLE`:

`ALTER TABLE table_like_this ADD PRIMARY KEY(Author_ID, Book_ID);`

If you do, here you go:

```
INSERT INTO table_like_this(Author_ID, Book_ID, Rating) 
VALUES (1,1,8) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Rating = 8;
```

[**See DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/88615a/1)

Comment: Sorry Gentleman,
My question is - Check for row exists - if exists then update - else insert.
A single query to do the insert or to update. 
Something similar to that of ON DUPLICATE for two row values.

Comment: Excellent. I dont have that much points to approve ur answer. worked like a charm. this this this is what i want.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

```
INSERT INTO table_like_this(Author_ID, Book_ID, Rating) 
 VALUES (1,1,8) 
 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Rating = 8;
```

Comment: @Nagarajan 
Sorry Gentleman, My question is - Check for row exists - if exists then update-else insert. A single query to do the insert or to update. . Something similar to that of ON DUPLICATE for two row values.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE tbl 
SET rating = 8 
WHERE `Author_ID` = 1 AND `Book_ID` =1;
```

Also consider having primary key for every table. It's a must! If your table is a join table, you should create multiple fields primary key (fields Author_id, Book_id)